# how to select list-items having index value within a certain range?

Tags: jquery

I want to assign a class to the list-items of an `ul li` list having `.index()` value between 10 to 20.

How do I select those elements using jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    li>Thirty</li>
</ul>
```

So I want something like

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    //Assign class 'classname' to those li elements 
    //between 10th and 20th (index numbers) in the list
    if([li element's index is between 10 and 20]).addClass('classname');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a subset of the elements in a selection:

```
$('li').slice(10, 20).addClass('classname');
```

Comment: thanks this one worked. I could not get the one from @Niklas working

Answer (score 2):

Although I recommend using lonesomeday's method, here is one way to do it purely with selectors:

```
$("ul li:gt(8) + li:lt(10)").addClass('classname');
```

Note that as `gt` and `lt` use 0 based index, if you want `>= 10` you need to use 8 (which is greater than 9).

example: http://jsfiddle.net/GybxF/21/

Comment: Not sure if this is how the [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) work.

Comment: @Salman Yes, I certainly would have thought that it should have ended with `li:lt(20)`, but that doesn't give the expected result. This however, does, which I do have to agree with you, doesn't seem right.

Comment: Yes actually it works, I just checked by changing all `UL` to `OL` in your fiddle.

Comment: The reason for this is that `gt` and `lt` both work on what is effectively an array. `gt` takes off the first few elements; `lt` receives the elements that are left from that operation.

Comment: @lonesomeday that certainly makes sense why it works as it does, but it doesn't seem to be the way it *should* be working in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Altough lonesomeday's answer is correct and probably better. Here is a different solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/E4U6Y/

HTH :)