# How to get only first three td tags except the first td with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get all values in the `td` tag as two questions below:

1. `2004 2005 2006`
2. An approximately: From **the third** `td` to **the fifth** `td` (**should use with**: `td.eq(3)` --> `td.eq(5)`). **The result must be:** `2005 2006 2007`

## **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/KjE3g/)</kbd>**

---

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="ms-vb-title">Year </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2004 </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2005 </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2006 </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2007 </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2008 </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2009 </td>
    <td class="ms-vh2">2010</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
 var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')").closest('table').find('tr').eq(0).find('td').not(".ms-vb-title");
 alert(arrayList1.text());
});
```

Comment: Related: [how to select list-items having index value within a certain range?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6250135/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
.find('tr').eq(0).find('td').slice(1, 4)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8EJ73/)

Comment: Thank you very much. The `slice(1, 4)` is very new to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var $firstThreeTds = $('tr:first-child td.ms-vh2').filter(function(index){
    return index <= 3;
});
```